# How should I design a cheap, shipping container class nuclear warhead?

Tags: warfare, nuclear-weapons, modern

Requirements:

- cheap (so rather not Pu-239 but U-235)
- easy and cheap to store for years with near zero maintenance (so no tritium and at most little plutonium, as admixture of Pu-240 would be source of irradiating neutrons)
- size - something that could be easily loaded in to shipping container (assume as rough approximation ISO 20 feet shipping container)
- at least 100 kilotons, but should be more as it would be very useful if could remain devastating even if detonated a dozen meters underground

Function:

- left in more exposed bases and fortified infrastructure facilities to prevent their capture
- hastily demolition of bridges, tunnels, etc.
- left as booby trap as some abandoned shipping container
- making any invader freak out whenever seeing an abandoned shipping container or truck (this could actually have more impact than direct damage)

Question:

- How it should be built to fit those requirements (my guess would be something akin to Ulam-Teller design, except primer being built of U-235 and not boosted)?
- What should be realistic yield when the limiting factors are price and ease of storage, while weight limit is highly lenient?
- How much roughly should it destroy when used against invading force to be worthy from purely attrition warfare perspective? (when left on route of invading force to clearly pay itself off it should blow up a tank platoon? tank company? tank battalion?)

Comment: VTC: You are allowed to ask one and only one question per post. You're asking at least six. Also, just to point them out... (a) Questions like this have probably placed every [worldbuilding.se] user on the U.S. Homeland Security watch list. Please be ***absolutely sure*** you're not trying to get ***too terribly realistic.*** (b) Also, set your expectations. Anyone who could answer this question with anything better than suspension-of-disbelief would have an idea worth millions of dollars to any of the nuclear powers and won't post it here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Regarding the containerized role:

- A [gun type weapon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gun-type_fission_weapon) should be more certain than implosion type when the explosives degrade in storage.
- The [Mark 8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mark_8_nuclear_bomb) comes at least into the ballpark of your yield.
- Fitting it into a container should be no problem at 37 cm diameter, 340 cm length, 1.5 tons.
- Long unattended readiness would be a problem, as per the infamous [chicken bomb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blue_Peacock). Would it be acceptable to make it a dead man switch when base power fails?
- The US is worried about, [among other things](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stockpile_stewardship), decaying explosives and electronics. How often can you take the plug and barrel (or pit) and put it into a new housing?

But historically, demolition charges were supposed to be man-portable, which this one is not. Different weapons for different roles?

Regarding your specific question on cost effectiveness, the answer is probably "no" when it comes to tanks. Nuking a deployed tank unit is not going to be cost-effective. To get most of a battalion in the field, you need a yield and targeting that is incompatible with a booby trap. The price of the weapons might drop with really large mass production, however. Thousands? Tens of thousands? Bury them at 100-meter intervals at the border, so that there will always be one in the right position?

Regarding yield limit, my proposal would probably be at the lower end, but ease of manufacturing could make it worthwhile.

Comment: OT: went down the rabbit hole with that link to 'chicken bomb'. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Although not a direct answer to your question - if I look at your list of Functions - there is nothing in there that necessitates the time, complexity and degradation (that is, the degradation of the associated components due to constant exposure to radiation) of Nuclear munitions.

The only thing that a Nuclear device would do over a conventional warhead would be a bigger bang.

For reference - a 40 ft Shipping container is over 2,000 square feet, using some back-of-envelope maths, a Kilotonne of TNT is expressed as a solide cube 27.8 ft on each side, so potentially 100 tonnes of TNT could fit in a 40 Ft container.

That's still a very very big bang, and if swap out TNT with something like RDX or another more powerful explosive, we get a bigger bang.

If it can't be destroyed with 100 tonnes of TNT, then you've probably got bigger problems.

For World Building in terms of a mass-produced, easily useable and versitile booby-trap type weapon system, a conventional explosive would make much more sense.